# Angular PrimeNG datetimepicker

Tags: angular, primeng

I use component calendar from PrimeNG 5.0.1, Angular 5.1, which allows to choose both date and time:

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="startAnalyzeModel" name="startAnalyze" [showTime]="true" [dateFormat]="dateFormat" disabled="true" [locale]="ru"></p-calendar>
```

But timepicker is frozen on time page was reloaded. Is it possible to update time value everytime when picker is shown? 
I have not found any parameter is in charge for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this problem, I use this code:

```
import { Calendar } from 'primeng/primeng';
...
@ViewChildren(Calendar) public cals: Calendar[];
...

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.cals.forEach(calendar => {
          let elem = calendar.inputfieldViewChild.nativeElement;
          elem.addEventListener('click', () => { 
            if (!elem.value) {
              calendar.initTime(new Date());
            }
          });
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are just missing font awesome included in your app. In order to change hours or minutes their arrows up or down need to be clicked. These arrows are rendered using awesome icons, something like:

```
<div class="ui-hour-picker">
  <a href="#" (click)="incrementHour($event)">
    <span class="fa fa-angle-up"></span>
  </a>
  <span [ngStyle]="{'display': currentHour < 10 ? 'inline': 'none'}">0</span>
  <span>{{currentHour}}</span>
  <a href="#" (click)="decrementHour($event)">
    <span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

[(Reference)](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/calendar/calendar.ts#L83)

Arrows classes: `fa fa-angle-up` or `fa fa-angle-down`

This is how it looks without font loaded:
[image]

Please note that minutes number is displayed within `<span>` HTML element (not `<input>`), thus it is not editable.

If I load [awesome fonts](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css) , then it looks like: [image]

Font awesome may be added in your `.angular-cli.json` file under `styles` section.

I created a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7bv266?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts.

If missing awesome font is not your case, please update my stackblitz and I will try to help.

**UPDATE**

In order to permanently set hours and minutes in the time picker we can use `defaultDate` calendar's input. In my example, I set it to current date and time 10:15, so it always show 10:15 unless changed explicitly.

HTML:

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="startAnalyzeModel" 
            [defaultDate]="defaultDate" 
            name="startAnalyze" 
            [showTime]="true" 
            [dateFormat]="dateFormat" 
            [locale]="ru"></p-calendar>
```

TS:

```
...
defaultDate = new Date();
...

constructor() {
  this.defaultDate.setHours(10);
  this.defaultDate.setMinutes(15);
}
```

`defaultDate` may be set to any desired date.

I updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7bv266?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) as well.

Comment: No, i have this arrows and i can set time manually. I want time to be set automatically to current time when picker is shown.

Comment: please see my updated answer and stackblitz with `defaultDate` solution

Comment: In your case it works only the first time(i always see 10:15). I need it works everytime when picker is shown and i could see current time.

Comment: sorry, I did not understand your question. Do you want to be as a clock, updating its time each minute, while it is open? If so, then do not use  `defaultDate` and in interval of 1 minute set`startAnalyzeModel` value to `new Date()`. Is that desired behavior?

Comment: startAnalyzeModel is null, so input is empty. I dont want to change it. I want to change timepicker value only(not input value!). Understand now?

Comment: @Andriy Спасибо друг!

Comment: @FindOutIslamNow Всегда рад помочь :)

Comment: Regarding the missing arrows: By default, primeng uses primeicons (pi), rather than font-awesome (fa) icons. The classes are "pi" rather than "fa". If you use primeicons, you don't need the custom span in your html, but you do still need to add primeicons to your project (e.g. with npm install primeicons --save, and also add @import to your style.css)

Comment: Thanks @GordonHopper for your reply, FontAwesome was replaced in the middle of 2018 (https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#600-beta1-2018-06-06), and the post was written half an year prior to this replacement. `span` tags and `fa` CSS classes came form the PrimeNG team: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/5.2.7/src/app/components/calendar/calendar.ts#L89